# how to disable before today date and time 9.00am-9.00pm using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

i have two fields one is date and another one is time.here user able to select date from today date to one month period(how to avoid selection beyond one month and before today).2nd field timepicker i need to validate only user can select 9.00am-9.00pm.

```js
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Date</span>
    <input type="date"  ng-model="bookdate" name="bookdate" >
  </label> 
    
  </div>
  <div class="col">
   <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label" >Time</span>
    <input type="time" ng-model="booktime" name="booktime">
  </label>
   
   </div>  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's input time directive supports setting min and max values in 24-hour format.

```
<input type="time" 
       ng-model="booktime" 
       name="booktime"
       min="09:00:00"
       max="21:00:00">
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btime%5D

Answer (score 1):

Please check below detail with explanation on `input[date]` and `input[time]`.

**For date:** [input[date]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D):

Parameter in detail:
min (optional) string  - Sets the min validation error key if the value entered is less than min. This must be a valid ISO date string (yyyy-MM-dd).

View:

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Date</span>
    <input type="date"  ng-model="bookdate" name="bookdate" max="{{bookdate | bookdate:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" max="{today}">
  </label>
```

For todate, modify your controller:

```
var today=new Date();
$scope.today = today.toISOString();
```

**For time:** [input[time]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btime%5D):

View:

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label" >Time</span>
    <input type="time" ng-model="booktime" name="booktime" min="09:00:00" max="21:00:00">
  </label>
```

Hope this help you well.

Comment: but max date should be dynamic not static value